# How to handle the STDOUT of a docker container with dockerpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerpy

I'm planning to write an app that can remotely control as well as interact with a container. Now the only problem is to handle the output.

With the help of docker-py, I can control docker. However, I want to control the STDOUT of the container. For example, I run a logging system in the container and want to redirect the output log to python STDOUT simultaneously or to the remote client.

How show I do it with docker-py or any other ways to implement it?

Comment: Like https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.attach or https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.logs ?

Comment: Yes, quite similar.Using `logs` works fine for the most situations. However, when run some commands like `vim` or `passwd` ,which needs interactions, I don't  know how to cope with it...